# Python - Pyzabbix Output Format

Tags: python, zabbix

I'm learning Python as i need to interact with Pyzabbix.
So, in the following output i just needed the last field, but i cant find a way to do this:

**EXAMPLE_HOSTNAME

{u'triggerid': u'8119464', u'description': u'Agent Zabbix unreacheable for 1 minutes'}**

And the script is:

`!/usr/bin/python
-*- coding: iso-8859-1 -*- from pyzabbix import ZabbixAPI import sys,csv from url='http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/zabbix' zh = ZabbixAPI(url) zh.login(user="Admin",password="XXXXXX") hostname = sys.argv[1] triggers = zh.trigger.get(filter={"host": [hostname]}, active="1",  output=['description']) print hostname for a in triggers:
    print a`

I appreciate any help.
Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Description field:

```
print a['description']
```